# How to make inductors larger?

Tags: circuitikz, scaling, lengths

I'm having a problem trying to make my cute inductors larger. I found a way of making them bigger with the `/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length` but that scales the entire inductor. I just want it to be larger, not thicker. What can I use?

Comment: Every component has its own size specification (relative to bipoles length).  So for "cute inductor" you can adjust, \ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/height/.initial=.3}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/lower coil height/.initial=.15} 
\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/width/.initial=.6}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/coils/.initial=5}

Comment: Thanks! That solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default definitions for the "cute inductor" are

```
\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/height/.initial=.3}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/lower coil height/.initial=.15}  
\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/width/.initial=.6}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/coils/.initial=5}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/coil aspect/.initial=.5}%percentage of inductor width, which is covered by lower coil
```

not all of which deal with size.  The following will create a inductor twice as large as the default.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[cute inductor] (2,0);
\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/height=.6}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/lower coil height=.3}    
\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/width=1.2}
\draw (0,1) to[cute inductor] (2,1);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]